# thread per request architecture implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to build a multithreaded server with TCP connections, that can talk to multiple clients and concurrently stream some data. I am using Java, Java IO and Java Thread libraries. I believe my implementation should be built as a 'thread per request' model. Any idea where I can kickstart or a tutorial you can point me into?

Comment: Google is your friend: [Oracle's concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: I googled it ofc, but was not able to find this, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

A thread per request model is quite simple to write, as multithreaded code goes.  Basically what you need is:

- A thread pool
- A server socket
- A main thread that dispatches worker threads

Set up the server socket to listen for requests.  Have the main thread run a loop.  The loop waits for a request to come in, then takes a thread from the thread pool to service the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a efficient Server. Use NIO. One thread per client is old way. It's memory/cpu intensive.

See this one. This is a good place to start.
http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/

Once you understand NIO and implement your server that way you will be glad you implemented it. In past I converted a One thread per client model to NIO and performance gains were tremendous.

Comment: The question says "thread per request" not "thread per client".